# Multiple Data Transfer Objects (DTO) for same entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, data-transfer-objects

I use multiple DTOs for a same Entity.
For example, my entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id //(with uuid generator)
    private UUID id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Attachment photo;
}
```

The problem is that request and response are not the same. For example, to register, a user must enter a `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, and `phoneNumber`. but not the `id` and `photo` (file). *I wrote another API that works with attachments*

I return the user as follows:

```
{
    "id": "c37f5b13-0698-41c8-a439-212484935567",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "phoneNumber": "123456789",
    "photoUrl": "/api/attachment/3ac27460-1c60-11ec-9621-0242ac130002"
}
```

and my DTOs:

```
public class UserDto {
    @Data
    public static class SignUpParams {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String password;
        private String phoneNumber;
    }

    @Data
    public static class SignInParams {
        private String password;
        private String phoneNumber;
    }

    @Data
    public static class ResponseParams {
        private UUID id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String photoUrl;
    }

    @Data
    public static class BlaParams {
        // Just the fields I want
    }
}
```

I think this method does not return unnecessary null values and is not displayed in Swagger Api Docs.
Is it right and best practices to use a nested class for dtos? or is there another better option?

Comment: This is probably a bit opinion-based, but anyway IMO, the idea of having different DTOs for the same entity depending on the exact usage is a good idea for me. The exact implementation (i.e. standalone classes or static inner classes) is another thing, again IMO depends on your needs!

Comment: There is nothing wrong having multiple DTOs: it is both semantic (your endpoints are aware of _limited set of data_ from your original objects and remains dedicated to a limited scope), and type-safe. At least these two points are a virtue to me. There are more, of course. By the way, `@Entity` is actually a DTO too, but for the JPA-only scope.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with your approach. Just wanted to add that another option is to use [Jackson's JSON Views](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Overall if you follow OOP paradigm, inheritance is usually a bad choice. However because we're talking about DTOs which can barely be considered classes in the first (instead they are usually structures w/o logic), I'd relax the requirements. After all, we rarely write code that follows only one paradigm.

With that said, it's possible to replace the inheritance with a composition by using Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped`:

```
class UserReqDto {...}

class UserResponseDto {
   @JsonUnwrapped 
   UserReqDto submittedData;
   ...
}
```

`@JsonUnwrapped` will embed fields of the enclosed object into the outer JSON.

PS: You should almost never use `@Data` - it implements `hashCode()` & `equals()` and it uses all fields for that. Do you compare your DTOs in production code? If not, why do you need `equals()` implemented in the first place? Most devs use this annotation simply because they are lazy and are fine with mediocre code.

Comment: Why is inheritance usually a bad choice? Could you elaborate on that? What's the difference to```UserResponseDto extends UserReqDTO``` ?

Comment: In OOP inheritance is considered a bad practice. But I can't cover it in a single paragraph, you can look up "Inheritance vs. Composition" - there are a lot of resources on this topic.